# complexity of for Loop having same variable name

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was trying this below code to find the time complexity and somewhere Lecturer said that here you have same variable name so time complexity would be O(n^3) , I think it should be O(n^6) can someone help me Iam confused

```
int i ;
for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
{
for(i=1;i<=n^2;++i)
{
for(i=1;i<=n^3;++i)
{
x=y+z;
}
}
}
```

Comment: `j` is unassigned?

Comment: sorry by mistake I put j it should be i let me edit it sir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: This is O(n^3) because first and second loop will be executed only once.

Comment: Here the 3rd `for` loop will run completely when it finishes the other two for loops conditions will fail. So Time complexity will be the complexity of 3rd for loop: O(n^3)

Comment: no no my question is totally different had the variable name in for loop is different complexity will be O(n^6) , I solved this problem a year ago in which lecturer said here variable name in each for loop is same so time complexity will be O(n^3) this i i want to know how

Comment: @thuva4 isn't it should be n*n^2*n^3 = O(n^6) where iam going wrong please clarify sir

Comment: ok I got it thanks to debug feature of turbo c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first for loop starts, then the second and the third. 
The third for loop runs until `i>n³`.
Once this happens, the second for loop will finish one iteration, it then tries to check if `i<=n²`, but since i > n³, it ends the loop. 
This happens for the first loop as well.

This happens mainly because the i variable is block scoped and since all three loops are nested, they all share the same variable.